# Strategy design pattern - stopping the method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, libgdx

I am working on a game in Java. I use libGDX as library. I am apparently using the **Strategy** design pattern.

Here is my SpawnMapScreen class. It extends BaseScreen.

```
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);

    npcTalking.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    npcRunning.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    WorldVars.player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    npcTalking.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    npcRunning.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();
}
```

Here is my BaseScreen class. It implements Screen.

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.graphics.setTitle("AHH V. " + version + " || Running at a mighty " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond() + "fps"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    WorldVars.player.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
    camera.position.set(WorldVars.player.getX() + WorldVars.player.getWidth() / 2, WorldVars.player.getY() + WorldVars.player.getHeight() / 2, 0);
    camera.update();

    spriteBatch.begin();
    font.draw(spriteBatch, version, 0, 100);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Here is my problem. In my BaseScreen class, I want to check if the escape key is pressed. If it is, I want to switch screens. The thing is, when I call my game instance's `setScreen(Screen screen)` method, it changes screen, but continues the process in the render method. It goes like this:

1. SpawnMapScreen's render(float delta) method is called
2. In the SpawnMapScreen's render(float delta) method, BaseScreen's render(float delta) method is called
3. In BaseScreen, it checks if the escape key is pressed, if yes, it changes screen
4. *Continue with SpawnMapScreen's render(float delta) method.*

How it should be working:

1. SpawnMapScreen's render(float delta) method is called
2. In the SpawnMapScreen's render(float delta) method, BaseScreen's render(float delta) method is called
3. In BaseScreen, it checks if the escape key is pressed, if yes, it changes screen
4. **Do not continue de SpawnMapScreen's render(float delta) method**

Is there a possible way to do like so?

Comment: Well, can you use your esc-key-detection method in your SpawnMapScreen class (since it's derived from BaseScreen)?

Comment: How are you switching screens?

Comment: @webuster I don't want to, because SpawnMapScreen is not the only BaseScreen instance. I also have cave1Screen, cave2Screen, etc. I don't want to copy paste the same code all around

Comment: @Lestat I am not showing how I actually switch screens in my code, but I just call my own method: `SimpleTools.switchScreens(Screen screen)`, which does a bit more things than just calling my Game's instance setScreen(Screen screen) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way I work around input-processing. In fact, I opted for an InputProcessor class (called InputSystem), so that I can treat all my inputs in the same place. Each time new BaseScreen is created, I also call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputSystem)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need a global (as in member of the class that this function is in) boolean flag to check in SpawnMapScreen to determine whether to do anything or not. Or it could check the current screen member for this.

Comment: Is'nt there a cleaner way of doing this? I mean your solution works, but is not the most optimal for reading comprehension... And having a flag would also include copy pasting the if statement...

Comment: You have a method `setScreen(Screen screen)` so I assume the value of `screen` is going in a member. So the cleaner way is to check that value, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as a case of using Strategy. The whole idea behind Strategy is a pluggable way of doing something. For instance, LayoutManagers in Swing or a sort (e.g. Bubble vs. Quicksort or whatever.. If you have a bunch of conditional logic, that should probably either outside the Strategy implementation.

Actually, in reading through it again, I have a concrete suggestion: use a State Pattern. What you would do is have 2 state handlers and then you listen on the escape key and when it has been pressed, you swap in the EscapeHandler, which implements the variant behavior before calling for the layout.